# Тестирование слоя валидации данных

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, юнит-тесты

Люди, подскажите хорошее решение. Имеется некий слой валидации данных, бизнес логики приложения и слой работы с БД. Есть правила накладывающие ограничения (например у некоторых сущностей есть 2 идентификатора [Guid и string определенной длины] и должно контролироваться отсутствие их дублирования с помощью валидации). При всем этом, при написании тестов возникает кейс что мы тестируем работу слоя валидации и нужно что бы валидация не прошла (т.к. в базе такой объект уже существует), либо наоборот прошла так как такого объекта еще нет. И тут возникает проблема потому что мы не знаем что есть а чего нет в тестовой базе. Возможный вариант решения это заранее наполнить базу некими сущностями и постоянно работать с ними, но такой подход не нравится тем что при написании теста приходится помнить что у нас есть в базе (да и тем более в других тестах могу создаваться новые сущности), а хочется что бы мы могли в каждом тесте создать N удобных для этого теста объектов и работать с ними. Но такой подход с обычной базой невозможен так как единственное решение которое я вижу, это нужно будет чистить базу в каждом тесте а это не быстро во всяком случае. Что приходит в голову это создать мок объекты работы с базой которые можно будет чистить в каждом тесте или создавать заново но это не кажется изящным решением. Собственно как решить проблему изящно ?
PS. Язык C# тесты встроенные в visual studio, использую entity-framework

Comment: Всё верно, нужно использовать мок. Инициализировать его перед каждым тестом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваши юнит-тесты вообще не должны подключаться к базе данных. Вы должны тестировать только ваш класс, отвечающий за валидацию, все внешние зависимости этого класса надо заменить моками. У вас должен быть мок, который будет притворяться, что он подключается к базе данных, но на деле никуда не подключаться, а просто возвращать подходящие для тестирования значения.

На примере одного теста. Скажем вы проверяете, что в базе нет двух элементов с одинаковым id. Тогда тест должен выглядеть примерно так:

- создаете мок класса для доступа к базе данных
- настраиваете нужный метод этого мока так, чтобы он возвращал заведомо неверные данные
- передаете этот мок валидатору и убеждаетесь, что валидация не прошла

Код примерно такой (в примере используется [nunit](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) и [moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)):

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    // arrange
    var dbRepositoryMock = new Mock<IDbReposiitory>();
    dbRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetItems()).Returns(new [] {new Item(){ Id = 1}, new Item(){ Id = 1}});
    var validator = new Validator();

    // action
    var validationResult = validator.ValidateItemsUnique(dbRepositoryMock.Object);

    // assert
    Assert.IsFalse(validationResult);
}
```

То есть идея вот в чем: вы создаете реальный экземпляр ТОЛЬКО для тестируемого класса. В нашем случае тестируемый класс - валидатор. Для всех зависимостей вы создаете моки, и настраиваете у этих моков ТОЛЬКО те методы, которые используются тестируемым функционалом, все остальные просто игнорируете. Например, у вашего репозитория может быть еще 20 методов, возвращающих разные сущности из базы данных, но если вы проверяете уникальность Item'ов, вы настраиваете возвращаемое значение только метода `GetItems()`, а все остальные методы просто игнорируете.

Про подключение к базе данных вообще забудьте, ваши юнит тесты должны выполняться без этого. Если вам сложно написать код в таком стиле - без реального подключения к базе данных, значит он плохо приспособлен для юнит-тестирования, и надо выполнять его рефакторинг.

Ваша попытка написать юнит-тесты с подключением к реальной бд довольно типичная ошибка для начинающих писать юнит-тесты. Я тоже пытался делать так и видел как то же самое пытаются сделать другие. Эта ошибка указывает на то, что вы не до конца понимаете *смысл* юнит-тестирования и вам стоит потратить время на чтение какой нибудь книги по этой теме. *"Разработка через тестирование" Кента Бека* будет отличным вариантом.

Comment: А для feature-тестов подключение к БД и проверка работоспособности кода прямо на ней допустимы?

Answer (score 3):

Строго говоря, вы пишете не юнит тесты, а, скорее, интеграционные тесты.

Если не ограничиваться ответом "тесты на базе это плохо, постарайтесь по возможности избегать этого" - то проще всего решить проблему чистки базы в интеграционных тестах отменой транзакции на каждом тесте:

- один раз создавать чистую базу при старте тестов (указанием DropCreateDatabaseAlways, или вручную, по статическому флагу)
- создавать новый TransactionScope в TestInitialize
- диспоузить этот  TransactionScope в TestCleanup, без вызова Complete

Работать будет не мгновенно, накладные расходы будут порядка 100-200 ms на тест, но для существующего (уже написанного без тестов) кода это самый быстрый вариант.

Eсли вы планируете рефакторить код в сторону лучшей тестируемости моками - лучше если к моменту рефакторинга у вас будут готовые тесты на тот код, который уже есть, пусть даже эти тесты будут медленными и будут делать реальные запросы к базе. Рефакторить непокрытый тестами код может только Чак. Для всех остальных это черевато затягиванием сроков, толпами новых багов и "в гробу я видал ваши тесты и рефакторинг" от ближайшего вверх по иерархии нетехнического начальника.

Кстати, ваш способ валидации ненадежен. Ничто не помешает гому потоку влезть в базу между проверкой с результатом "все ок" и вставить туда дубликат. Такие проверки все равно надо дублировать констрейнтами на уровне базы.

Comment: Что за Чак такой?